# Raspberry Pi zero and USB wall charger

Tags: pi-zero

I have 3 Raspberry Pi zero but limited electric sockets. Is it possible to connect and power them using a USB wall charger? Any 220V model recommendation?

Answer (score 4):

In theory YES, you can use a USB wall charger... and here comes the BUT:

- Make sure they have an appropriate rating. 5V 1A should be sufficient for Pi Zero.
- Make sure those are not too old ones that came with a mobile phone (I think of 2007 and prior). (The problem is, some of them provide even more than 6V. While this is fine for charging a battery, it will burn your Pi)

If you don't have the equipment to verify yours than have a look here:
[Power adapters](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Power_adapters)